# PubNub - Code that worked once but doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, socket.io, publish-subscribe, pubnub

A year and a half before, I used to test PubNub and I had a testcase that worked pretty well.
Now, I'm trying to get back where I left to go on testing but, for a reason I don't get, I can't make my chatroom work anymore (demo account).

For your information, I use Punbub with socket.io and here is what's inside my html file:

```
<html>

    <head>

        .....

        <script src="http://cdn.pubnub.com/socket.io.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        ....

        <script type="text/javascript"> 

            ....

            var pubnub_setup = 
            {
                user          : 'xxxx',
                channel       : 'shoutbox',
                publish_key   : 'pub-c-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                subscribe_key : 'sub-c-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            };

            var socket  = io.connect( 'http://pubsub.pubnub.com', pubnub_setup );

            ....

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

These keys are up to date (I created a brand new account) but nothing happens.

If I open firebug, I have "Network Connection Errors" everywhere, each second.

Here is one of them:

"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://ps12.pubnub.com/v2/presence/sub_key/sub-c-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/channel/shoutbox?uuid=0&pnsdk=PubNub-JS-Web%2F3.6.7"

And If I use the demo interface of the Pubnub website with the same keys, I get a:

"["SUBSCRIBE ERROR",{"message":"Forbidden","payload":{"channels":["shoutbox"]}}"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This typically means that you have enabled Access Manager on your account. This immediately blocks all access to PubNub (using those keys) unless access has been granted. To resolve this issue quickly, just disable Access Manager on your account until you are ready to implement Access Manager into your application (granting access using auth-keys).

For more information on Access Manager, see the following links.

Grant Access:
http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html#grant

Read more about PAM:
http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/access-manager/

Security with PAM:
http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/overview/security.html